# Generalized Mean Value Theorem for integrals (in $\mathbb{R}$) with $c$ in the open interval $(a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, riemann-integration

I want to prove this:

- If $f : [a, b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $g$ is an integrable function that does not change sign on [a, b], then there exists $c\in (a, b)$ (open, please) such that $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = f(c)\int_a^b g(x)dx. $$

I have seen some demonstrations that find $c\in[a,b]$. How can I obtain such a $c$ in the open interval $(a,b)$?

In one of my textbooks, the author put as an exercise this implication:

- If $g>0$ (the previous conditions are in game) and $$ \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = f(a)\int_a^b g(x)dx,$$ then there is $c \in(a,b)$ such that $f(a) = f(c)$.

But, we assume $g>0$ instead (for example) $g\geq 0$. Can we prove this implication assuming only $g\geq 0$? If not, can we directly prove the mean value theorem described above assuming $g\geq 0$? How can we do it?

Comment: are you sure you know how to prove the first statement  ?

Comment: @user1952009 with c in the closed [a,b] I know. The problem is c in the open (a,b)

Comment: how would you prove that it exists $c \in [a;b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx = f(c) \int_a^b  g(x) dx $ ???

Comment: @user1952009 like this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Proof_of_the_First_Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Definite_Integrals

Comment: $m =\min_{x \in [a;b]} f(x)$ and $M = \max_{x \in [a;b]} f(x)$. that $f$ is continuous implies that for every $y \in [m;M]$ there is $x \in [a;b]$ such that $f(x) = y$. finally bound $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx$ in term of $m$ and $M$ and you'll get a proof that you can easily modify to get what you need

Comment: @user1952009 the problem is $x\in[a,b]$ instead $x\in (a,b)$!