# A Detail in Mean Value Theorem for Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, mean-value-theorem

Here is the most common and basic version of the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals:

> Let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b]$. Then there exists $c \in [a, b]$
> such that $f(c) = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx$.

My question is: **Can we change the existence interval for $c$ from $[a, b]$ to $(a, b)$? And if so, why is the version above much more commonly seen even though it is weaker?**

Two proofs are usually presented, one by applying the Mean Value Theorem for Derivatives to the function $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$; the other using the Extreme Value Theorem and the Intermediate Value Theorem.

For the second method, I think we can avoid some technicalities by considering the case where $f$ is a constant function and the case where $f$ is not a constant function separately.

Otherwise, I don't see why we need $c \in [a, b]$ instead of the tighter one $c \in (a, b)$.

Edit:
Here are some examples which use $[a, b]$:

- p.474 of the book "Calculus - Early Transcendetals, 9th Edition" by
  James Stewart et al.
- Exercise 16 on p.215 of the book "Introduction to Real Analysis, 4th
  Edition" by Robert G. Bartle et al.
- https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_210_Calculus_I_(Seeburger)/05%3A_Integration/5.03%3A_The_Fundamental_Theorem_of_Calculus

Comment: See: https://byjus.com/maths/mean-value-theorem/

Comment: See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4121087/148510) which reduces to your case when $g(x) \equiv 1$. This proves we can always find $c$ in the open interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: That is what OP is asking about , @RRL , **why** that theorem is using $[a,b]$ when $(a,b)$ is "Better" : Proof is useful , though that is not the Issue here.

Comment: There is a simple proof of the $c\in[a,b]$ version of the theorem ([example](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Cosumnes_River_College/Math_401%3A_Calculus_II_-_Integral_Calculus/01%3A_Applications_of_Integration/1.08%3A_The_Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Integrals)) in which there is a step that shows the existence of $c\in[a,b],$ but the premises of that step are not strong enough to show $c\in(a,b).$ So you would have to work a little harder (or use a different approach entirely) to show $c\in(a,b).$ I suppose some authors don't think that juice is worth the squeeze.